# How do I detect the OpenJDK in my applet (System Properties)?

Tags: applet, java

How can I determine if my client is running OpenJDK with a web plugin? I've tried java.version and the rest of the properties listed [here](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm).

Running `java -version` from the terminal works fine, but if I went this route, java would have to be on the user's path, which I don't know if I can trust entirely. Is there any other way to see the string given by java -version programmatically, without shelling out to the command line or terminal?

Right now, when I run `System.getProperties().getProperty("java.version")`, I get `Sun Microsystems Inc.`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it via system properties, but firefox provides a navigator.plugins array containing all installed plugins. If you check the "name" property of each plugin, you should be able to separate the Sun Java plugin from imitators.